# Facing errors while Setup Maven Java project in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In my project “flexicore” I am facing one problem. There are some jar specification errors are there in the project.
When the jar error is showing the total errors it is showing as ‘2’ when I add those jars, those 2 errors are going out but newly 8 errors are coming as below.

The declared package "com.nokia.flexi.flexitaf.metadatalanguage.types" does not match the expected package "com.nokia.flexi.flexitaf.metadatalanguage"  AbstractPatternSelectorType.javal  line 1   Java Problem
The declared package "com.nokia.flexi.flexitaf.jobplanlanguage" does not match the expected package "com.nokia.flexi.flexitaf.jobplanlanguage.types" JobPlanResult.java     line 1  Java Problem
The type MavenManager is already defined    MavenManager.java
The method copyDirectory(File, File, boolean) in the type FileUtils is not applicable for the arguments (File, File, TestcaseRepository.ResultCopyFilter)   TestcaseRepository.java line 369    Java Problem
The type Utils is already defined   Utils.java
The method setDefaultFileLogger() is undefined for the type Util    CustomStandalone.java
The type MavenTest is already defined       MavenTest.java
The type ArtifactDependency is already defined  ArtifactDependency.java

The same is repeating for some jars. I tried to add & remove all the available jars but no luck . Can u give me some idea.

Comment: Where is the Code..?

Comment: If you are using maven, you should not add external jars - only dependencies in POM.